# How get Matrix4x4 from Pose from ArCamera in ARCore NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, arcore

On Google [Samples](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples) I can get samples about getting the **Matrix** from a **Pose** generated by an `ArAnchor` or from a `ArPlane`. But when I'm trying to get from `ArCamera` is not working, my result is an **Identity Matrix**.

Small part from my code:

```
ScopedArPose scopedArPose(ar_session_);
ArCamera_getPose(ar_session_, ar_camera, scopedArPose.GetArPose());
std::array<float, 16> out_matrix_col_major_4x4;

ArPose_getMatrix(ar_session_, scopedArPose.GetArPose(), out_matrix_col_major_4x4.data());
```

**What is working:**

`ArSession` is working, `ArFrame` is ok, I'm able to get `ArCamera`, `ArCameraIntrinsics`is ok, `ArImage` is ok, `AImage` is ok.

Format and NumberOfPlanes from Image are ok.

`ScopedArPose` class is equal from google samples. `array<float, 16>` works fine, tested in google samples.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem it needed to check the camera state before.

```
ArTrackingState camera_tracking_state;
ArCamera_getTrackingState(ar_session_, ar_camera, &camera_tracking_state);
// If the camera isn't tracking don't bother to go forward
if (camera_tracking_state != AR_TRACKING_STATE_TRACKING) {
    LOGI("ARCoreOdometry: Camera Not Tracking");
    return;
}
```